# Login page: password validation

Tags: bug, status-completed, sign-up, validation

I have noticed a typo in the password validation field when you [sign up on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup).

---

When your password is 6 characters or less, this gets displayed:

> [image]

Quoting the text:

> Must contain at least 6 more characters.

It should be:

> Must contain at least 6 ***or*** more characters.

Update:

In order to demonstrate what is happening here do the following:

1. go to the password field and type a letter and a number.
2. click the sign up button.
3. type over 8 characters in the password field now.
4. the error will stay there until you move to a different field. This happens on every field not only password! I just noticed it when entering a password.

Answer (score 5):

The minimum length requirement is for 8 characters.

The length message tells you how many more characters are required so the message is entirely correct.

As you type, the number will change - the message you have pasted would be shown once one letter and number have been typed in. Meaning 6 more characters/numbers are needed. If you type one more, the number will be 5... etc...

---

Now that you posted an actual repro, the issue was that the old (red) error message was not clearing even after the password was changed - this was visible after the info message (blue) was removed when the minimum password length was reached.

I have fixed this specific issue - the fix will be in the next build.

Comment: This is not happening for me.

Comment: @shnisaka - what browser/OS are you using (and versions)? Any extensions running?

Comment: Latest version of safari.. On mac. Running adblocker

Comment: From all the up votes, I think I am not the only one who is experiencing the problem.

Comment: It is working now!

Comment: We have made no changes.

Comment: I am going to edit my question! Now I know what is going on.. there is still a bug.